# TypeScript Duplicate errors after upgrading to VS 15.5.4

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, definitelytyped

I was previously on Visual Studio 2017 15.1 and had no errors at all. The project is building fine, all of the errors are coming from Intellisense.

I have DefinitelyTyped definition files in my project.

The errors I'm receiving include

- Duplicate string index signature (JQueryUI)
- Duplicate identifier on `export = jQuery` (JQuery)
- Cannot redeclare blockscoped variable 'jQuery' (JQuery)
- Cannot redeclare blockscoped variable '$' (JQuery)
- Duplicate identifier (project namespace)
- Cannot find namespace (project namespace)

This is in a .NET Core project with TypeScript 2.5. I don't have a tsconfig, the project settings can be seen in the image below: [image: project settings]

Comment: Do you reference `@types/jquery` in your `package.json` file as well? Have you tried deleting your whole `node_modules` folder and re-creating it (`npm i`) ?

Comment: @Igor nothing in package.json about jQuery. Only things I have are some Gulp dependencies. I haven't tried deleting the node_modules folder - I'm not getting any errors that relate to it.